# How to select two fields from a table using join with another table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a books database.

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `book_subject` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'What genre the book is to be picked up from subject table',
  `book_subject2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'What genre the book is to be picked up from subject table',
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Let's say a book xyz falls under two subjects 'Mystery' and 'Thriller' with id values 1,2 in 'subject' table.

How do I write a select query that fetches the 'subject_name' value for both 'book_subject' and 'book_subject2'

Comment: Now I am stuck at second step. 
How do I get a total number of books from both the fields. 
Let's say XYZ book has 'Mystery' and 'Thriller' as subject  'book_subject' and 'book_subject2'. Another book ABC has 'Thriller' and 'Romance' as 'book_subject' and 'book_subject2'. How do I show the total count of 'Mystery' as 1, 'Thriller' as 2 and 'Romance' as 1?

Comment: Don't use MyISAM; use InnoDB.  And have a PRIMARY KEY on each table.

Comment: Can you please help me with the sql query? I have book_id and subject_id are primary keys already

Comment: I augmented my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join on the same table twice:

```
select books.book_id, books.book_name, 
subject1.subject_name as sub1, subject2.subject_name as sub2
from books
join subject as subject1 on subject1.subject_id = book_subject 
join subject as subject2 on subject2.subject_id = book_subject2 ;
```

Have a bridging table:

```
create table book_subject_mapping
(
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_subject` int(11) NOT NULL 
);
```

... and use it to join. More flexible

Comment: It worked, thank you so much, after only 4 hours of searching - stack exchange and it's senior members to the rescue.
I would really appreciate if you could guide me to an example or tutorial or implementation of the EAV model you wrote about above.

Comment: I wouldn't call this an EAV model, but simply a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

It is messy and tedious.  You would need a `UNION` or `OR`, plus worry about `NULL`.

It would be better to have a separate table relating `book_id` and `book_subject`, and allow any number of rows in that table.  This has the benefit of allowing more than a fixed "2".

**Counting**

```
SELECT  book_subject,
        SUM(ct) as ct
    FROM  ( 
            ( SELECT  book_subject, COUNT(*) AS ct
                    FROM  books
                    GROUP BY  book_subject )
            UNION  ALL
            ( SELECT  book_subject2, COUNT(*)
                    FROM  books
                    GROUP BY  book_subject2 ) 
          ) AS s
    GROUP BY  book_subject;
    WHERE  book_subject IS NOT NULL
```

That gets the counts by id; then another `JOIN` is needed to get the names.

Or, if you avoid splaying an array (subjects) across columns...

I would not have a mapping table, but simply a tagging table (1:many instead of many:many)

```
create table subjects
(
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject_name` VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL 
);

SELECT  subject_name,
        COUNT(*) as ct
    FROM  subjects
    GROUP BY  subject_name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I am getting this error

"[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM  
            (
                SELECT  book_subject2, COUNT(*)
        ' at line 10
"

Comment: Oops, a typo. I hope there aren't more.

Answer (score 1):

Just do two joins, one for each subject.

```
SELECT b.*,
       s1.name,
       s2.name
       FROM books b
            LEFT JOIN subject s1
                      ON s1.subject_id = b.book_subject
            LEFT JOIN subject s2
                      ON s2.subject_id = b.book_subject2;
```

Comment: And indexes?...